# Quelle est la différence entre « j'ai sommeil » et « je dors » ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, expressions-idiomatiques

J'ai écouté la chanson *7 heures du matin* de Jacqueline Taïeb et je me suis rendu compte qu'elle dit « j'ai sommeil » dans les paroles. Est-ce que cela signifie la même chose que « je dors » ?

Comment: Bienvenue sur French.SX. J’ai fait quelques corrections, n’hésite pas à regarder l’historique d’édition (en cliquant sur « éditiez *date* » à côté de la signature) pour voir ce que j’ai modifié et, si tu ne comprends pas certaines choses, n’hésite pas à poser des questions.

Comment: Parfait ! Je les ai regardé et elles sont très utile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

« [Sommeil](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sommeil) » a plusieurs sens. L’un d’entre eux est « besoin de dormir » ; c’est ce sens qui est employé dans l’expression « avoir sommeil ». « Avoir sommeil » signifie donc « être fatigué », « avoir besoin de dormir », et nécessite donc d’être éveillé.

Comment: Merci beaucoup (et aussi pour les corrections ;))

Comment: Tout à fait. La différence est la même qu'entre « j'ai faim » et « je mange ».

Answer (score 2):

"J'ai sommeil" signifie : j'ai envie de dormir.